# Returning a static variable

Tags: java, static

I am programming something in Java and in my main-class, i have a static class variable called "file-system".
Now i want to give the variable file-system to a method from another class, which needs some information from file-system, and modifies it in some ways.
Now I am wondering: Do i have to return the new file-system from my method that is modifying it? Or is the modification taken over to my file-system in main-class due to the "static" attribute?

I don't know what else to write here, but i cannot post my question yet because editor tells me it does not serve the quality standards. Seriously, who had the idea to do a quality analyzing tool which is completely messed up and does not even let me post a single question?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I think you may need to learn some more about static variables. You should need to pass it the other class can just access it (providing its public) http://www.caveofprogramming.com/articles/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the static variable is also declared public then your other class can modify it "in place" - just reference the variable:

```
MyClass.fileSystem = ....
```

Comment: That's really bad architecture though.

Comment: OMG, that is it! And it was right in front of my eyes the whole time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of your static variable. Intrinsic types (such as int, char, boolean) are **copied**, no matter how static it is, while for objects the *reference* (or a pointer if it's more clear to you) is kept.